# What could be causing slow Http requests to https://api.telegram.org/ with Python on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, telegram

Http request to https://api.telegram.org/ takes a super long time to complete
I'm using python on my macbook pro m2

```
% sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.3.1
ProductVersionExtra:    (a)
BuildVersion:       22E772610a
```

```
 % python --version
Python 3.11.3
```

I have two scripts:

```
# requests_test.py
import time
import requests

start = time.time()
response = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/')
print('Time:', time.time() - start)
```

```
# httpx_test.py
import time
import httpx

start = time.time()
response = httpx.get('https://api.telegram.org/')
print('Time:', time.time() - start)
```

And here some test results:

```
% python test/requests_test.py 
Time: 151.9861559867859
```

```
 % python test/httpx_test.py 
Time: 5.838088035583496
```

```
% docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)/test:/app/test" python:latest sh -c "pip install requests && python /app/test/requests_test.py"
...
Time: 1.3224074840545654
```

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)/test:/app/test" python:latest sh -c "pip install httpx && python /app/test/httpx_test.py" 

...

Time: 1.0409996509552002
```

```
 % curl -o /dev/null -s -w "Time: %{time_total}\n" https://api.telegram.org/
Time: 1.922458
```

Interesting huge difference between using requests library and httpx as well as running it on host(macos) and docker container

What is more interesting is that when i'm trying other websites i'm not facing this issue, only with https://api.telegram.org/

Tried different versions of python as well

Comment: I don't think this is a Python or *requests* issue. This runs in ~0.2s on my system (macOS 13.4). You may need to look at your network set-up

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about networking, I've tried only switching between home wifi and mobile hotspot which didn't show any difference. I figured that docker container would use same thing so could not refer to network. Would you suggest something to try out?

Comment: You can probably eliminate Python and/or *requests* with *curl*